# Different words for incoming and outgoing delivery

Tags: synonyms, business-language

In German there are different words for *Incoming Delivery* and *Outgoing Delivery* (Anlieferung and Auslieferung).

Are there some words in English that have similar distinction?

The closest match I could find is *Supply* for incoming and *Delivery* or *Shipment* for outgoing.

Comment: As a pair, shipping and receiving work like that. [signage](https://www.google.com/search?q=shipping+and+receiving+signs&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&sxsrf=ALeKk02gScQQIsyVAL7XEliRImO_CMxY1A:1619431565851&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijpOHZ1JvwAhWQZM0KHWYyADcQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1093&bih=500)

Comment: [***deliveries*** and ***despatches***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deliveries+and+despatches%2Cdeliveries+and+dispatches&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) (or ***dispatches***).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be context dependant.

*Imports* and *exports* are words that have the specific distinction incoming and outgoing, however they refer to things transported to/from another country. In an airport or train station, *Arrivals* and *Departures* have the distinction.

But in the context of say, a company with freight, *Deliveries* or *Arrivals* would usually refer to that which is incoming, and for outgoings it could be *Despatch*. In context, *Unloading* and *Loading* might be used to refer to the areas, teams, tasks etc. that are related to incoming and outgoing deliveries respectively.